# tuple index out of range / int object is not iterable

Tags: python, range, out

the following problem occours:
I'm trying to detect faces and call a function with the specific index values

```
 faces = face_cascade.detectMultiScale(gray, 1.3, 5)
            facesCopy = faces
            print("faces at 0")
            print(faces)
            if(len(faces) >= 1):
            for (i) in range(len(faces)):
                  #call function with values of faces at specific index(i)
                  detectFace(self, faces[i])
```

faces returns this: [[247 101 237 237]]
facesCopy the same, but faces[i] returns [247 101 237 237]

how do I get the inner array?
faces[0] returns truple out of range
or any variation of faces[0][0] or [0][0][0][0] returns in a for loop int object is not iterable:

```
for (x,y,w,h) in faces[0]:#do stuff
```

What am I missing or to blind to see?
I'm guessing it has something to do with the packed array? 
The values are x and y postion and width and height of the face.
Thank you for any help or suggestions

Comment: Did you get the answer to your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`detectMultiScale` returns a list of rectangles.

`[[247 101 237 237]]` would be a single one, as in an array with one rectangle/array.

```
for face in faces:
    print(face)
```

Outputs:

```
[247, 101, 237, 237]
```

If you want to unpack the array into variables:

```
x, y, w, h = face
```

I'm not sure what arguments `detectFace` requires thought.

If you only want the first rectangle, just access it by index:

```
faces[0]
```

Comment: sorry, for the late response! but yes, this helped a lot! Thank you